# How to create tables in SQL when they reference each other in SQL server. Furthermore how to ensure no errors pop up during data insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Employee and Customer Account. The employee advises the customer account:
Here is the SQL I have written for the Employee Table. (Don't mind the `Person(PersonID)`, it works, since the Person has no foreign keys. But the `Customer(SSN)` reference suffers from this issue as well.):

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
SSN Varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Manages  Varchar(50),
PersonID varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(PersonID ),
Advises  varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CustomerAccount(AccountNo),
);
```

And here is the SQL for the Customer Account Table:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerAccount(
AccountNo   Varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
AdvisiorID  VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(SSN),
OwnerSSN    Varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(SSN),
);
```

As we can see I can't create either CustomerAccount or Employee since both of them depend on each other. How should I resolve this issue?

Also when inserting using insert statements, it would probably give errors entering data, How should I resolve that?

Comment: Before you even begin to deal with the foreign key issues you need to rethink your table. Storing SSN in plain text is borderline criminal. That data needs to be encrypted at all times and should NEVER be the primary key. Use anything else as your primary key, an identity column, a guid, literally anything that is not a person's SSN.

Comment: This looks at a high level like a many to many relationship. The way to solve that is to use a bridge table.

Comment: This is a uni assignment, Not a real life system

Comment: Then shame on your professor for giving such a horrible structure and making it seem like this would be ok. And also shame on them for using such a silly datatype as varchar(50) to hold a max of 10 characters.

Comment: To my embarrassment, this was my doing. I'll see myself out.

Comment: Ah well chock that up to a learning experience then. No biggie. For the question at hand see my comment about a bridge table.

Comment: The point Sean is making above is that a professional/professor should know better than to use a 50 character data type for a 10 character value. Someone new may not, which is fine, provided you learn from it.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, it's not super common to have foreign key constraints on both tables that reference each other.  Much more typical to have the foreign key constraint in the child table, referencing a primary key in the parent table.  Do you really need to ensure that an Employee can't exist unless it has an associated CustomerAccount?  Or is it sufficient to ensure that a CustomerAccount can't exist without an Employee?